# working with custom hash array in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I already posted a similar question but i got told to try and solve it myself and post here what i have so far.

What i'm doing is calling some xmlrpc methods to extract some data from an external app.

what i can do so far is display contents from a simple array as per below.

```
<%  @attachment.each do |att| %>
<div class="item">
    <%= image_tag att %>         
</div>
```

What i want is to be able to pass a hash array similar to this:

```
 {id:"1", content:"somedataaa", imgurl:"someurl.com/image.jpg"}
```

what i want is when the user clicks on an image to pass the id to a controller method so i can then go and get more data with the id provided and provide another view.

```
 <%  @hasharray.each do |att| %>
    <div class="item">      
     <%= att.id %> //this could be hidden an only used to pass the id to a method
    <%= image_tag att.url %> //add a link_to here somehow to route to a method on the controller.        
    </div>
```

I know how to do this with rails model data, but since this data is coming from an external xmlrpc i have to pass it as a hash array.

Could you please guide me to how i need to do this, is this the right way, or can i parse the hash array and somehow save it to a Rails model so i can then use the view as normal and  have access to the routes.

Comment: Are you coming from PHP? It's a hash, not "hash array" :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
attachments = [{ :id => 1, :url => 'images/1.jpg' }, { :id => 2, :url => 'images/2.jpg' }]

attachments.each do |attachment|

  link_to image_tag(attachment[:url]), "/path/to/controller/#{attachment[:id]}/show"

end
```

Side note: Please follow proper naming conventions. Don't name variables "hasharray" or "hash" or "array" or anything similar. Make them meaningful. Please.

Reading this will help: http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html

Comment: Thanks for this, do i need to do a custom route or can i just pass it like this "controllername/#{attachment[:id]}/show"

Comment: ouch, can you help me with that? like i said i've only used the rails models before, never anything to custom.

Comment: actually i'm getting the array as such {"id"=> 1}, so i get troubles when doing attachment[:url]

Answer (score 1):

You can just pass the hash instead of a model, and us `att[:id]` instead of `att.id`.

If you really need it to be a model instead of a hash, you can look at Hashie, which provides several methods to convert a hash to a model:
https://github.com/intridea/hashie

Comment: thanks for that, will look into it if the above option doesn't work for me, as im no good with custom routes.